# Jade template : nest mixin

Tags: javascript, express, pug

Below mixin

```
mixin form(title, action)
    legend title
    form.form-horizontal(method='post', action=action)
        label Name:
        input(type='text',name=Name,id=Name)
```

renders to

```
<legend>title</legend>
<form method="post" action="save" class="form-horizontal">
  <label>Name:</label>
  <input type="text"/>
</form>
```

Now, I extracted the label and field into another mixin

```
mixin form(title, action)
    legend title
    form.form-horizontal(method='post', action=action)

mixin field(name)
    label #{name}:
    input(type='text',name=name,id=name)
```

and use as

```
mixin form("xxxx", "save")
    mixin field('Name')
```

This gives error

```
>> Line 1209: Unexpected string
Warning: Jade failed to compile test.jade. Use --force to continue.
```

is it possible to nest mixin and how to make it render as the first output.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it should be possible. At least the guy here was able to.

https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/1103

Comment: This guy from the link is very laconic but he is right. Actually I spent some time trying to figure out what he meant so maybe this will be useful for somebody. **You have to add block statement at the end of declaration of the containing mixin.**

Comment: I am not into mixin anymore but I think you just have to add "block" in the end as Oscar said. Like the link shows but only once. https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/1693

Answer (score 1):

```
mixin field(name)
    label #{name}:
    input(type='text',name='#{name}',id='#{name}')

mixin forms(title, action, name)
    legend #{title}
    form.form-horizontal(method='post', action='#{action}')
    block
    +field(name)
```

Test Call

```
+forms( '*TheTitle*', '*TheAction*' , '*TheName*' )
```

Renders

```
<legend>TheTitle</legend>
<form method="post" action="TheAction" class="form-horizontal"></form>
<label>TheName:</label>
<input type="text" name="TheName" id="TheName"/>
```

You must define the mixins separately and then invoke the 'field' mixin within the definition of the 'forms' mixin.